# PHP textfile value to array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, text

I have `$data` variable like this:

```
$data = [  'name'                => $name,
           'student_id'          => $student_id,
       ];
```

and I want to save it to text file:

```
$path = storage_path('app/public/').'student.txt';

        if (is_file($path)) {
            
            $path_ = Storage::disk('public')->prepend('data.txt', json_encode($data).',');
        } else {
            
            $path_ = Storage::disk('public')->put('data.txt', json_encode($data).',');
        }
```

and then I want to see the output:

```
$json = (Storage::disk('public')->get('data.txt'));
return $json;
```

and the value is:

```
{"name":"Michaela","student_id":"1202"},
{"name":"Zach","student_id":"1524"},
```

I want to have the output like this:

```
{
    {"name":"Michaela","student_id":"1202"},
    {"name":"Zach","student_id":"1524"},
}
```

So whenever hit this function, new array will append inside {   } .. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

the output you are needing is actually not valid JSON. the valid format would be,

```
[
   {"name":"Michaela","student_id":"1202"},
   {"name":"Zach","student_id":"1524"},
]
```

to get this format change your code to following

```
$data[] = [
      'name'=> $name,
      'student_id'=> $student_id,
];
```

for example,

```
$data[] = [
      'name'=> 'A',
      'student_id'=> 'a',
];
$data[] = [
      'name'=> 'B',
      'student_id'=> 'b',
];
```

Before Saving to the file, encode the $data varibale in json,

```
$jsondata = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: sorry but, it just return with 

[{"name":"Michaela","msg":"1202"}]
[{"name":"Zach","student_id":"1524"}]

Im hoping for valid format just like your comment, but its not working

Comment: this should work. here is a working example. btw have you used json_encode($data) before saving to a file?

 $data[] = [
      'name'=> 'A',
      'student_id'=> 'a',
];
$data[] = [
      'name'=> 'B',
      'student_id'=> 'b',
];


print(json_encode($data));

Comment: thank you it works, but this way is for one to go(?) for my case, the data come one by one so i think the final result will be like my first comment, the bracket will wrap one by one not a whole data

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by the data come one by one. if this means you need to use the txt file as a database i would not recommend it but you can open the file when data is recieved and read the content and then append new data. if one by one means they come in batchs, you can use a loop.